# How to solve for the value of a discrete random variable without brute force? (Poisson Distribution)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Say I had a question like so:

$X$ ~ $Po(3.1)$

Given $P(X < a) = 0.8$ (1 s.f) 
Solve for $a$

I can brute force it by summing the value of the probability mass function at $X=0$, $X=1$, $X=2$ etc. up until I reach the probability of $0.8$

If I do that, then I get: $a = 5$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{4} [\frac{e^{-3.1} \cdot 3.1^{k}}{k!}] = 0.7981... $$

$ = 0.8$ (1 s.f)

so I get $P(X < 5) = 0.8$ thus $a=5$

My question is: is there a cleaner and non-brute-force method of solving for this?

Comment: You could look for the $80\%$ percentile of a normal distribution with mean $3.1$ and variance $3.1$ and get about $3.1 + \sqrt{3.1}\times 0.842 \approx 4.58$ and then guess that the answer could be $4$ or $5$, and then check

Comment: The quantile function of a distribution is the inverse CDF. In R, `qpois` is the quantile function of a Poisson distribution. Thus R code `qpois(.8, 3.1)` returns $5.$ The Poisson CDF is `ppois`. Thus, code `ppois(5, 3.1)`, returns $0.9056662.$ And `ppois(4, 3.1)` returns $0.7981895.$ Because Poisson distributions are discrete, you can't expect a perfect 'hit'.// Alternatively, if you can find a printed CDF table of $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 3.1),$ scan down the probability column for the nearest entry to $.8$ and look for in the corresponding integer in the neighboring column.